# VBA - I need to lift specific figures from an excel sheet and move them to another tab

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some issues with my code any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a range of data in a tab called Wheel Diameters and I need the following criteria to be met (Columns B6 to B28, G, L need to be less than 4000 and the cell values need to be 800 or less) the second is (Columns B35 to B54, G, L need to be more than 4000 but less than 5000 and the cell values need to be 800 or less) the third is (Columns B61 to B92, G, L need to be 9000 or greater and the cell values need to be 800 or less) for the information to be lifted into another tab called Wheel Diameters league.

The less than 4000 need to go into the wheel diameters league tab in columns A and B, the greater than 4000 but less than 5000 need to go into columns D and E, the greater than 9000 need to go into columns G and H.

[image: Sample of 3000 table]

```
Sub BUTTON5_Click()

Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

'Change worksheet designations as needed
 Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Wheel Diameters")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Wheel Diameters League")

Target.Range("A2:B5000").Clear

j = 2     ' Start copying to row 2 in target sheet

For i = 1 To 3 'Number of ¿wees?
For Each c In Union(Source.Range(Cells(6, 5 * i - 2), Cells(28, 5 * i +    1)), Source.Range(Cells(35, 5 * i - 2), Cells(54, 5 * i + 1)), Source.Range(Cells(61, 5 * i - 2), Cells(92, 5 * i + 1)))

    If c.Text < 4000 And c.Text <= 800 Then

        Target.Cells(j, 1) = Source.Cells(c.Row, 5 * i - 3)
        Target.Cells(j, 2) = Source.Cells(5, c.Column)

       j = j + 1

    ElseIf c.Text <= 800 And c.Text >= 4000 Then

        Target.Cells(j, 4) = Source.Cells(c.Row, 5 * i - 3)
        Target.Cells(j, 5) = Source.Cells(5, c.Column)

       j = j + 1

    End If

Next c

Next i

End Sub
```

Example of how it looks:

3405 - As it is greater than 800 the details Column 1 and 3405 will be lifted and copied into a second tab called 'Wheel Diameters League'

[image]

[image: 4000 & 9000 on the wheel diameters sheet]

[image: wheel diameters league layout]

Comment: I am slightly confused as to what you are trying to achieve. Can you show how the output will look like for `3405`?

Comment: How could `c.Text <= 800 And c.Text >= 4000` ever happen? How can something be both less than (or equal to) 800 and more than (or equal to) 4000?

Comment: @CLR I am currently using `If c.Text <= 800 Then` but I now need to also look at the information based on what number it is 3000 goes into specific columns 4000 will go into a different one

Comment: Hi Paula, I think I understand what you want now. Based on your example data, I've built something that creates your output. However, your example data doesn't have any coach numbers starting with a 4 so I'm not sure where they would appear. Check out my answer and you might need to tweak some of it to cover *all* your data.

Answer (score 0):

This works on your example data:

```
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet
Dim rg As Range
Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long, tcol As Long, threshold As Long

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Wheel Diameters")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Wheel Diameters League")

Set rg = Source.Range("B6:P92")

For x = 1 To rg.Columns.Count Step 5
    For y = 1 To rg.Rows.Count
        For z = 1 To 4

            Select Case rg.Cells(y, x)
                Case 0 To 3999
                    tcol = 2 ' column 'B'
                    threshold = 800
                Case 4000 To 8999
                    tcol = 5 ' column 'E'
                    threshold = 864
                Case Else
                    tcol = 8 ' column 'H'
                    threshold = 849
            End Select

            If rg.Cells(y, x + z) > 10 And rg.Cells(y, x + z) <= threshold Then
                    With Target.Cells(Rows.Count, tcol).End(xlUp)
                        .Offset(1, 0) = rg.Cells(y, x)      'write Coach No
                        .Offset(1, 1) = z                   'write Axle No
                        .Offset(1, 2) = rg.Cells(y, x + z)  'write value
                    End With
            End If
        Next z
    Next y
Next x
```

I've added a new variable called `tcol`, which is the target column we're writing the league data to. I've created a `Select Case` to decide what column it's set to, based on the axle class.

I've added `threshold` which is also based on axle class.

I've expanded the range down to `P92` to read ALL the data.

I've added a test to ensure the value is above 10, not just below `threshold`. This prevents cells that are *not axle data*, but are axle *headings* from triggering the writing to the league table.

I've made the `For.. Next` loops for `x` and `y` more dynamic, in case your tables change size - in which case you just need to alter the `rg` range.

Lastly, I've added in the writing of the value to the table, as I hadn't noticed that requirement before.

Comment: sorry only getting a look at this now.. I'm having an issue with the information in the wheel diameters league pasting into the wrong place... its pasting into columns B&C rather than A&B - also would I be able to apply the same sort of rule for my other sets (4000 and 9000 range) if I just use separate buttons? I'm assuming this may be the easier option @CLR

Comment: The `.Offset(1, 0)` and `.Offset(1, 1)` specify where to write the data, so if you changed those to `.Offset(1, -1)` and `.Offset(1, 0)`, you'd shift the outputs left 1 cell.

Comment: Where are the tables for 4000 and 9000? Different tabs or just other ranges?

Comment: that would make sense i tried everything bar a -1 now I feel stupid thank you...the 4000 and 9000 are on the same sheet just further down - I will update my question with a screenshot

Comment: I'm going to alter my answer a little. I'll add some notes on what I've done so hopefully it'll make sense..

Comment: Just noticed the threshold changes based on class. Give me a few more minutes to add that in.

Comment: Thanks @CLR that makes a lot more sense to me with the wee write up underneath the only thing is when I run it, it bugs out at `If rg.Cells(y, x + z) > 10 And rg.Cells(y, x + z) <= threshold Then`

Comment: Let me know what the error reads. Also, when it's still in error mode, hover your mouse over each of the variables, x, y, z and threshold and note what each one currently holds.

Comment: it comes up with a run-time error '13' Type Mismatch... x is 11, y is 46, z is 2 and threshold is 800, the only thing is even though this comes up as an error and asks you to debug all the correct information copies to the next tab

Comment: I think it's being caused by the #N/A in `$N$51`. You need to either error trap in the code to ignore errors, or make sure there are none in the table beforehand.